# Creating an interconnected menu in Python

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm teaching myself Python/Pygame, and to start off I'm trying to make a basic menu that the user can scroll through and then select an item to go to a different menu.  My initial thought was to define the menus as a tuple of menu items, with each item being a tuple of what text to display and where selecting that item leads you.  So, for example:

```
mainmenu = (("Go to Menu 1",menu1),("Go to Menu 2",menu2))
menu1 = (("Go to Menu 2",menu2),("Return to Main Menu",mainmenu))
menu2 = (("Go to Menu 1",menu1),("Return to Main Menu",mainmenu))
```

then have a function like `makeMenu(menu)` that prints out a given menu, and allows the user to scroll through it.  When the user makes their selection, `makeMenu(menu)` is called again, this time being passed the menu that corresponds to the currently selected option.

The problem is that Python won't allow you to define `mainmenu` in terms of other menus that haven't been defined yet.  This makes sense, but I can't think of a way to create a series of interconnected menus without defining them relative to each other.  I'm sure there's a simple solution, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Often, for menus, I like to use the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). A fully fledged one may be overkill for your current needs - but it should lead you in the right direction. An example of this for C, specifically talking about game states, is available on [gamedevgeek.com](http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/).

This may not directly answer your questions, but it should lead you to a much more extensible and robust solution.